# Animated Checkboxes and Radio Buttons with SVG add default checked

Tags: javascript, svg, checkbox, radio-button

I'm using this code: https://tympanus.net/Development/AnimatedCheckboxes/
to build a nice animated radio button and it works very nicely. But I need to add a default radio button checked when a user gets the page. I want that one of the radio options will be already checked.
now the code works only when you click one of the options.

Comment: Whenever you click checkbox some function is called. Just call that function in the start of script.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed that issue change the function (controlRadiobox) to this

```
function controlRadiobox( el, type ) {
        var svg = createSVGEl();
        el.parentNode.appendChild( svg );
        if (el.checked) {
            draw(el, type);
        }
        el.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
            resetRadio( el );
            draw( el, type );
        } );
}
```